# How to remove any control using MAUI .Net?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-maui

I am new with MAUI and I cannot find any solution in the web, I want just delete any control or component. A component can be a listView, button, or anything.

For example I the following code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiApp2.Prueba"
         Title="Prueba">
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">

    <ListView x:Name="FruitListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding FruitName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Button x:Name="btnDelete"
        Text="Random Color"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        Clicked="btnDelete_Clicked" />


</StackLayout>
```

How can I delete the entire `<ListView>` when I click the button `btnDelete`?

I have this:

```
    private void btnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FruitListView. ;
}
```

I cant find any reference to delete this `ListView` component, is it possible through backend code?

Comment: FYI: Usually it is sufficient to *hide* the control. `FruitListView.IsVisible = false;`.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove a control from its parent layout like this

```
MyStackLayout.Children.Remove(FruitListView);
```

You will need to assign an `x:Name` to the parent layout in order to reference it in the code behind

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can delete a control at runtime **if it began its life in the original XAML at compile time**.  WPF does much in the way of custom code generation during compilation and MAUI is no different.

A better approach would be to move the `ListView` from adding-to-the-window-at-compilation-time to *adding-to-the-window-at-**runtime***.

In other words:

1. delete the `<ListView>` and related from the XAML file
2. in your page's code-behind C# .CS file, create a `ListView` object and add it to the `StackLayout` object.  Save the `ListView` object to a field like `ListView _myListView`
3. Later you can just `StackLayout.Remove(_myListView)`